Issue recording a new canvas stream with Kurento Recorder
I am using kurento-utils, v7.0.0, to stream and record a videocall between two users.
I am using Kurento Media Server 7 and the file format of the recorded videos is in WEBM.
I am altering one of the user's video by using a canvas to create a background image filter.
I have noticed that if I pass the canvas stream as the videoStream parameter in the WebRtcPeer.WebRtcPeerSendrecv() method, I am able to see the altered video on the receiving end.
Most of my code is similar to the Javascript-NodeJS tutorials of Kurento's repository on GitHub (one2one-call, recorder)
call() {
  let options = {
    remoteVideo: this.videoInput,
    // localVideo: this.videoOutput, // Replaced with videoStream
    videoStream: this.virtualCanvas.captureStream(), // New canvas
    onicecandidate: (candidate: any) => {
      this.onIceCandidate(candidate);
    }
  };

  // Unaffected code
  this.webRtcPeer =
    kurentoUtils.WebRtcPeer.WebRtcPeerSendrecv(options,
      (error: any) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
          return;
        }

        this.webRtcPeer.generateOffer((error: any, offerSdp: any, params: any) => {
          if (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
          let message = {
            id: 'call',
            from: this.name,
            to: this.clientCallId,
            call_id: this.callId,
            sdpOffer: offerSdp
          };
          this.sendMessage(message);
        });
      });
}

However, when I check the recording it has a filesize of 0.
I've tried manually changing tracks and sending the video's stream instead however I would either not see the expected result on the receiving end or the recorded filesize would be 0 bytes.
let senders = this.webRtcPeer.peerConnection.getSenders();
let videoTrack = senders.filter((s) => s.track.kind === 'video')[0];
videoTrack.track.stop();

let displayVideo = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
videoTrack.replaceTrack(displayVideo);

this.videoOutput.srcObject = stream;

Is there anything that would make Kurento recorder to record the canvas stream that is sent?
